# Angular application compiled successfully but isn't loaded in the browser, also throwing a lot of unknown errors in the console

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I upgraded my Angular application from Angular 6 to Angular 14, after a lot of work I finally solved all the errors and the application was compiling successfully. But now when I open the local server to take a look at it, it doesn't display anything on the screen just a small div and some of my components.

There are a lot of web socket related errors in console.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://lms.localhost/ng-cli-ws' failed: 
[webpack-dev-server] Disconnected!
[webpack-dev-server] Trying to reconnect...
```

After this most of the errors are coming from main.js and polyfill.js

```
main.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'show')
    at template (main.js:1:2358105)
    at Eg (main.js:1:4163057)
    at pd (main.js:1:4161822)
    at lb (main.js:1:4168843)
    at K1 (main.js:1:4162698)
    at pd (main.js:1:4162709)
    at Uu (main.js:1:4169505)
    at Q1.detectChanges (main.js:1:4172019)
    at c.tick (main.js:1:4231256)
    at c._loadComponent (main.js:1:4231564)
```

Most of the errors are similar to this and looking into the main.js and polyfill.js file I didn't found anything useful it felt like it was just full of gibberish.

> I found out that when some components are initiated their constructors are called but their ngOnInit() methods aren't called.

Can someone help me out at-least in finding where the error maybe coming from. This is the output that I am getting [Output of my browser and console screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yj59K.jpg)

Edit :- The issue was due to Bootstrap, there were a lot of breaking changes in Bootstrap 4 to 5, so we reverted Bootstrap, and migrated Bootstrap separately using it's guide.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow Angular Documentation to upgrade your package
check this link [click here](https://update.angular.io/?v=6.0-14.0)

Comment: Yeah, I followed the official guide only.